# Async-Await doesn't automatically update component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, httpresponse

I have this simple webpage that can add or remove things to/from a list. There's an http request function(`sendRequest`) inside a custom hook that I use to dispatch various requests to the server, the requests themselves work but the list doesn't update automatically with the requests, I have to do it manually by refreshing the page. If I replace the async-await code with fetch it does update, so I'm sure the issue is with this function or something closely related. http.jsx is the custom hook where I define the requests and ingredients.jsx is where I actually render and manage the requests.

To be more precise, the `<IngredientList />` component in the `ingredients.jsx` is the one I need to automatically update the render with my async-await code in `http.jsx`.

http.jsx:

```
import { useReducer, useCallback } from 'react';

const HTTP_ACTION = {
  SEND: `send`,
  RESPONSE: `response`,
  ERROR: `error`,
  CLEAR: `clear`
};
const { SEND, RESPONSE, ERROR, CLEAR } = HTTP_ACTION;

const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  error: null,
  data: null,
  extra: null,
  identifier: null
};

const httpReducer = (currentHttpState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SEND: {
      return {
        loading: true,
        error: null,
        data: null,
        extra: null,
        identifier: action.identifier
      };
    }
    case RESPONSE: {
      return {
        ...currentHttpState,
        loading: false,
        data: action.responseData,
        extra: action.extra
      };
    }
    case ERROR: {
      return { loading: false, error: action.errorMessage };
    }
    case CLEAR: {
      return initialState;
    }
    default: {
      throw new Error(`HTTP Error: Should not be reached!`);
    }
  }
};

const useHttp = () => {
  const [httpState, dispatchHttp] = useReducer(httpReducer, initialState);

  const clear = () => useCallback(dispatchHttp({ type: CLEAR }), []);

  const sendRequest = useCallback(
    async (url, method, body, reqIdentifier, reqExtra) => {
      try {
        dispatchHttp({ type: SEND, identifier: reqIdentifier });

        const response = await fetch(url, {
          method,
          body,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        });

        const responseData = await response.json();

        dispatchHttp({
          type: RESPONSE,
          responseData,
          extra: reqExtra
        });
      } catch (error) {
        dispatchHttp({
          type: ERROR,
          errorMessage: `Something went wrong! ${error.message}`
        });
      }
    },
    []
  );

  return {
    isLoading: httpState.loading,
    data: httpState.data,
    error: httpState.error,
    sendRequest,
    reqExtra: httpState.extra,
    reqIdentifier: httpState.identifier,
    clear
  };
};

export default useHttp;
```

Related code in Ingredients.jsx:

```
import { useReducer, useCallback, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';

import IngredientForm from './IngredientForm';
import IngredientList from './IngredientList';
import ErrorModal from '../UI/ErrorModal';
import Search from './Search';
import useHttp from '../../hooks/http';

const INGREDIENT_ACTION = {
  SET: `set`,
  ADD: `add`,
  DELETE: `delete`
};
const { SET, ADD, DELETE } = INGREDIENT_ACTION;

const ingredientReducer = (currentIngredients, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET: {
      return action.ingredients;
    }
    case ADD: {
      return [...currentIngredients, action.ingredient];
    }
    case DELETE: {
      return currentIngredients.filter(({ id }) => id !== action.id);
    }
    default:
      throw new Error(`Should not get there!`);
  }
};

const Ingredients = () => {
  const [userIngredients, dispatch] = useReducer(ingredientReducer, []);
  const {
    isLoading,
    error,
    data,
    sendRequest,
    reqExtra,
    reqIdentifier,
    clear
  } = useHttp();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isLoading && !error && reqIdentifier === `REMOVE_INGREDIENT`) {
      dispatch({ type: DELETE, id: reqExtra });
    } else if (!isLoading && !error && reqIdentifier === `ADD_INGREDIENT`) {
      dispatch({
        type: ADD,
        ingredient: { id: data.name, ...reqExtra }
      });
    }
  }, [data, reqExtra, reqIdentifier, isLoading, error]);

  const addIngredientHandler = useCallback(
    ingredient => {
      sendRequest(
        `https://db-training-2efa8-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/ingredients.json`,
        `POST`,
        JSON.stringify(ingredient),
        ingredient,
        `ADD_INGREDIENT`
      );
    },
    [sendRequest]
  );

  const handleRemoveItem = useCallback(
    listIngredientId => {
      sendRequest(
        `https://db-training-2efa8-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/ingredients/${listIngredientId}.json`,
        `DELETE`,
        null,
        listIngredientId,
        `REMOVE_INGREDIENT`
      );
    },
    [sendRequest]
  );

  const filteredIngredientsHandler = useCallback(filteredIngredients => {
    dispatch({ type: SET, ingredients: filteredIngredients });
  }, []);

  const ingredientList = useMemo(() => {
    return (
      <IngredientList
        ingredients={userIngredients}
        onRemoveItem={handleRemoveItem}
      />
    );
  }, [userIngredients, handleRemoveItem]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {error && <ErrorModal onClose={clear}>{error}</ErrorModal>}

      <IngredientForm
        onAddIngredient={addIngredientHandler}
        loading={isLoading}
      />

      <section>
        <Search onLoadIngredients={filteredIngredientsHandler} />
        {ingredientList}
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Ingredients;
```

Feel free to look at the [full project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-eeqimw?embed=1&file=src/App.jsx) at Stackblitz, though the only relevant pages are "http.jsx" and "ingredients.jsx".

I've tried a lot of things but nothing worked so far. I'm really lost at what I have to do.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, but . . . there doesn't seem to be anything in your callback that *would* update the component, unless that's inside the `dispatchHttp` function that you haven't posted (is that from a framework?), in which case I have to wonder how that function finds the component to update. Can you explain a bit about how you expect this to work?

Comment: @ruakh useHttp is a custom hook, the component is updated within "ingredients.jsx". I have edited and posted both pages in full. I'm not using any frameworks, only Vite and hooks like useReducer. The expected behavior is to automatically update the ingredients list when I either add or remove an item. That works if I use fetch inside the "sendRequest" function but doesn't work with async-await. I have to manually refresh the page to make them appear on the list. The full project link has a practical example of what my issue is.

Comment: @ruakh To be more precise, the "<IngredientList />" component in the "ingredients.jsx" is the one I need to automatically update the render with my async-await code in "http.jsx".